# “Could not find a part of the path” Error For File Read Operation in Azure WebApp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have `MVC application` which is having browse button I'm selecting file any location and reading file content using path and then process the content.

Works fine in local but when published on azure as web app obvious it was not able to get the file system path but how to handle this?

> Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\mydata.json'.

**Index.cshtml**

```
 <label>File Path</label>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.filePath, new { type = "file", @class = "input-file" }) )</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
private static void Test(string filepath)
        {
            string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            JArray array = JArray.Parse(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Azure the process current working directory is `D:\Windows\system32\`, try `var wholePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), filepath);` to locate files under web root.

**Update**

Add `HttpPostedFileBase` field to your Model. In your View, change to `m => m.File`.

```
public class FileModel 

{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(FileModel fileModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         StreamReader s = new StreamReader(fileModel.File.InputStream);
         JArray array = JArray.Parse(s.ReadToEnd());
         ...
     }
     return View();
}
```

Comment: but i'm uploading file from UI from any location folder will it work?

Comment: @Neo Do you have some code to save file on your web server? This method is to read file that has been uploaded to your web.

Comment: no i do not have any code because i was thinking i will directly read file content only and process that content further .. is it necessary to save file ?

Comment: @Neo No, you can read file stream from upload file and no need to save it on server. I can post an example later if needed.

Comment: can you please because when I published the same code and try to read file using any given path i'm getting error :(
'D:\Windows\system32\mydata.json' actual file path i selected was `C:\myfiles\mydata.json`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read a file that is *on a client machine* in code that's *executing on the server*. That won't work. Your server doesn't have access to files in the client machine. Which is a good thing

Have a look at [HttpPostedFileBase](https://www.google.com/search?q=httppostedfilebase) to upload files.